# Free/OpenSource Antivirus Software for Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows, open-source, windows-10, antivirus

I need some recommendation on **free** or **open source** antivirus software for **Windows 10**.

Can anyone tell me about it? **Thanks**

Comment: Did you even Google? What was wrong with what you found? Try https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-anti-virus-software.htm Also, try reading [ask] - the more information that you cab give us, the better that we can help you

Comment: @Mawg while I agree on a little lack of research: where does that TechSupportAlert even mention "open source"? My Ctrl-F didn't find the word "open" on that page. And all the products mentioned there seem to be proprietary/commercial (at least the ones I recognize – not being a Windows user and thus not needing such a "resource killer").

Comment: Izzy, the OP asked for "free ***or*** open source".  I have been looking for freeware & share for decades now, and TechSupportAlert is simply ***the best*** source that I have found fro Windows s/w. I don;t even know of another which reviews, rather than just listing s/w. It is the first site that I visit when looking for anything.  While that page may not have mentioned open source, rest assured that the site only ever lists free s/w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For open source antivirus solution, the most recommended is **[ClamAV®](https://www.clamav.net)**.

> ClamAV® is an open source antivirus engine for detecting trojans,
>   viruses, malware & other malicious threats.

Features

- Open source antivirus software which is actively maintained
- ClamAV includes a multi-threaded scanner daemon, command line utilities for on demand file scanning and automatic signature updates.
- ClamAV supports multiple file formats, file and archive unpacking, and multiple signature languages.

However if you are just looking for a free alternative you can go with [Windows Defender](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-defender) (Remember **free for personal use** is not necessarily **open source**)

- The obvious reasons in case of the latter option is that,

> it is integrated in Windows, officially supported by Microsoft, and
>   works in collaboration with Windows Updates to keep your systems
>   secure.

Credits

- [What is the best open source antivirus software?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-open-source-antivirus-software)

Comment: ClamAV is just a command-line tool. If you want GUI you'll also need to install ClamTk.

Comment: @BagasSanjaya are you sure that applies to the Windows variant? The [ClamTk page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clamtk/) writes "for Linux".

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot o free antivirus solutions. I would recommend using [360 Total Security](https://kubadownload.com/360-total-security-download.1274.html) from [Qihoo 360 Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qihoo_360).

> 360 Total Security is a great software to protect your system against viruses, trojans, malware, etc. This antivirus suite is using four security engines: 360 Cloud Engine, 360 QVMII, Avira and BitDefender.

The software works fast and this is the most important thing for users. Of course with priority for protection against viruses.

The second option I would recommend is [Kaspersky Free](https://kubadownload.com/kaspersky-free-download.1600.html). The software uses the same engine as other [Kaspersky Lab](http://kaspersky.com) products. It's safe regarding online antivirus tests, and it works also fast.

Comment: "Russia Has Turned Kaspersky Software Into Tool for Spying: Searches exploited popular Russian-made antivirus software to seek classified material, officials say."
by Shane Harris and Gordon Lubold, Wall Steet Journal, October 11, 2017 https://www.wsj.com/articles/russian-hackers-scanned-networks-world-wide-for-secret-u-s-data-1507743874